# How to use decltype as the LHS of a larger type expression when compiling under VS2010-VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, decltype, declval

I've got two versions of code both using `decltype` and `declval`. One works and one doesn't. They are included below. I've tested this on VS2017 and below and I get the same results. VS2018 will compile it. GCC and Clang both compile it all.

The error that is generated for the failing case under MSVC is

> [x86-64 MSVC 19 2017 RTW #1] error C3646: 'type': unknown override
>   specifier

for the line

```
typedef typename decltype(boost::declval<Func>()(SegmentVec()))::value_type type;
```

See [God Bolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tkTefT) for a live version of the below code.

```
#include <vector>
#include "boost/type_traits/declval.hpp"

typedef std::vector<int> SegmentVec;

/////////////////////////////////
// The below fails
template <typename Func> struct Traits {
    typedef typename decltype(boost::declval<Func>()(SegmentVec()))::value_type type;
};
template <typename F> auto Hof(F f) -> typename Traits<F>::type {
    return f(std::vector<int>{2})[0];
}
/////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////
// The below works
template <typename Func> struct Traits2 {
    typedef typename decltype(boost::declval<Func>()(SegmentVec())) type;
};
template <typename F> auto Hof2(F f) -> typename Traits2<F>::type {
    return f(std::vector<int>{2});
}
/////////////////////////////////


int main(){
    auto lmd = [](std::vector<int> const & a){return a;}; 

    Hof(lmd);
    Hof2(lmd);
}
```

Is it possible to get the code to compile under MSVC 2010 upwards without significantly changing the code. The code in itself above is an extraction from a larger body of code and doesn't necessarily have any meaning apart from demonstrating the compiler error.

Comment: No repro, VS2017 15.8 with `/permissive-` and `/std:c++17` compiles this code fine. Note that godbolt VS compilers are outdated. Also there is probably no need to use `boost::declval` since `std::declval` is available.

Comment: The question as asked for a fix for VS2017 **and below** down to VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To please that buggy MSVC, you can do it in part ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/w6Xa4r)):

```
template <typename Func> struct Traits {
    typedef decltype(boost::declval<Func>()(SegmentVec())) suptype;
    typedef typename suptype::value_type type;
};
```

`using Tnew = Told;` is a better syntax though ;)

Comment: VS2017 15.8 with /permissive- and /std:c++17 compiles OP's code fine. Note that godbolt VS compilers are outdated so there is no point to use it to demonstrate VS bugs.

Comment: @VTT Thank you, I have no MSVC at hand right now. We might want to close the question.

Comment: Note that I said VS2017 and below. I am supporting down to VS2010 and the solution as provided fixes my problem.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Then I guess you should change title to VS2015 - VS2010

Comment: @bradgonesurfing do /permissive- and /std:c++17 work also?